# security handling in wcf web api and wcf jquery support

Tags: jquery, .net, wcf, rest

What are the security options in wcf next ("wcf web api" and "wcf jquery support") ? And if a client requesting to a wcf service by jquery, how can wcf dedect if it's really my client code or a spider app / my altered js (requesting with parameter combinations) that is crawling my database ?

Best Regards,

Serdar Irmak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can wcf dedect if it's really my client code or a spider app / my altered js (requesting with parameter combinations) that is crawling my database ?

Well, you can't. Everything that an unauthenticated user could do on some page with jquery could be simulated by a bot. So your only chance is to use some sort of authentication.